ONNX Runtime Inference using GPU : libcublasLt.so.11 not found
Im trying to run inference using ONNX runtime on my server GPU. However im getting this error:
2024-08-10 23:53:29.404983674 [E:onnxruntime:Default, provider_bridge_ort.cc:1745 TryGetProviderInfo_CUDA] /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/session/provider_bridge_ort.cc:1426 onnxruntime::Provider& onnxruntime::ProviderLibrary::Get() [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : Failed to load library libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so with error: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
After looking into my server cuda files, I noticed that i have libcublasLt.so.12 instead of 11. I have the latest versions of ONNX-runtime and ONNX-runtime gpu installed.
How do i fix this? I dont have admin permissions on the server so cant really downgrade cuda or something of that matter.

You had noticed that your ort required cuda 11 (libcublasLt.so.11) but your current cuda version is 12 (libcublasLt.so.12).
You may go to ort cuda ExecutionProvider to check your ort-cuda-cudnn compatibility, find the best ort version for your system.
Don't forget to add cuda libs into dynamic library search path, for Linux, you may write as export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} , usually the path already added when you install cuda.

If you already have CUDA 12 (as indicated by libcublasLt.so.12), you can try using the onnxruntime-gpu version for CUDA 12.
You can install this version with the following command (refer to https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/install/ Install ONNX Runtime GPU (CUDA 12.x) for more details):
pip install onnxruntime-gpu==1.18.0 --index-url https://aiinfra.pkgs.visualstudio.com/PublicPackages/_packaging/onnxruntime-cuda-12/pypi/simple/

Version 1.18.0 is compatible with CUDA 12 and cuDNN 8.9. For additional versions, see the ONNX Runtime CUDA Execution Provider documentation.
